# Add time and IP before bash cursor on Linux server SSH

Tags: linux, bash, debian, vps

I was thinking about syntax looking like this:

`IP: 123.123.123 | 28.10.2016 17:24 | root@vps:~$`

Is it possible?
I wish log bash history with this data for debugging and backup.

I was try on it, but time is static and I don't know how write IP:

```
echo "force_color_prompt=yes" >> /root/.bashrc
echo "PS1='$(date +%T) | ${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '" >> /root/.bashrc
```

Maybe IP can be printed only first time after SSH login, is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that the time will *always* be the time when the prompt is *displayed*, not when a command was actually *executed*.

Comment: Does your Debian know `hostname -I`?

Comment: @Cyrus yop, it works. But I need just IPv4.

Answer (score -1):

For IP getting printed out, add following lines to your .bashrc:

```
ip=`ip a | grep wlan0 | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | head -1`
echo $ip
unset $ip
```

Now when ever you open a new terminal, your will get ip printed out for you. Same goes for ssh.

Please notice that Im using my `wlan0` adapter to get the ip, you may need to change that to `eth0` depending on your environment.

Answer (score -1):

Set ip with Farhad's answer, then:

```
PS1='IP: $ip | \D{%d.%m.%G %H:%M} | \u@\h:\W$'
```

The time is dynamic.

### References

> [Controlling the Prompt - Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt)
>
> [STRFTIME(3) - Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)